# React component not updating with current state but mapStateToProps is updating

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to React and am trying to build a Redux store based off the Todo Example.  I can add a Todo item and the state updates but for some reason the component won't update.

```
   // This works and the console.log matches the current state.
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      console.log('map state to props', state);
      return {
        todos: getVisibleTodos(state.todos, state.visibilityFilter)
      }
    }
```

But the component props don't update, todo's is just a blank object {};  I simplified the component code here:

```
    class TestTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      todos: props.todos
    };

    // Shows 0 todo's
    console.log('constructor props', props.todos)

    setTimeout(function() {
      // Still 0 todo's even though mapStateToProps & the UI shows 10.
      console.log('constructor props', props.todos);
    }, 2000)

    /* DEMO */
    this._addTodo = this._addTodo.bind(this);
    /* */
  }

  // Add fake to do item.
  _addTodo(index) {
    this.props.dispatch(
      addTodo(
        'test: ' + index,
        'test lastName: ' + index,
        'test dob: ' + index,
        '999-999-9999',
        'testing@test' + index + '.com',
        'Test - ' + index
      )
    )
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Add 10 todo items.
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
      this._addTodo(i);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Table
          ...
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

TestTable = connect(mapStateToProps)(TestTable)

export default TestTable
```

Comment: What does the getVisibleTodos() function look like

Comment: It's currently set to show all but even without that it's the same issue:  const getVisibleTodos = (todos, filter) => {
  switch (filter) {
    case 'SHOW_ALL':
      return todos
    case 'SHOW_COMPLETED':
      return todos.filter(t => t.completed)
    case 'SHOW_ACTIVE':
      return todos.filter(t => !t.completed)
  }
}

Comment: What all do yo see when you console.log(this.props) in render()

Comment: just a blank array []

Comment: I posted an answer, not sure if it's a great solution or not though

Answer (score 1):

you can use react.16 life-cycle method to set state or watch props change:

the first method should return a new state object.

the second method will execute when component props or state changes.
[componentDidUpdate](https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/postrender_with_componentdidupdate.html)

```js
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  return nextProps.todos === prevState.todos ? {} : {todos: nextProps.todos}
}

//do not forget to use props changes conditionally, otherwise, you will get call stack exceeded error.
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevProps.todos !== this.props.todos) {
    this.setState({todos: this.props.todos});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the component seems to fix the issue, not sure if this is best practice though.

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    console.log('component will receive props', props);
    console.log('props todos: ', props.todos);
    this.setState({
      todos: props.todos
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    console.log('component will receive props', props);
    console.log('props todos: ', props.todos);
    this.setState({
      todos: props.todos
    })
  }
```

this code is quite bad, because you card it will create an infinite loop. Each time you make `setState`, it will re-render the component and call the function `componentWillReceiveProps`. Which will `setState` and it wil re-render.... 
To prevent the loop, i usually add an if around the setState to stop the loop on when you get to what you want

Can't make a comment to your previous answer, so I'm writing this here